# Expired links for images

Tags: discussion

What to do with things [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19787/1853)? With broken links on the images, the answer is incomplete...

[image]

Comment: related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/577/how-to-deal-with-dead-links

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127450/238438. There isn't much that can be done. Try leaving a comment notifying the OP of the issue, and suggest that they use the built in image upload function to avoid this happening in the future

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to try and recreate the images.... It might take some guesswork, but it is still possible.

Comment: I can only think of two ways to prevent things like this from happening: making sure that an image doesn't disappear by automated backups, and making sure that you allways type in your answer what you can see on the image, so the answer isn't worthless without the images. (type "uncheck the combined render pass" instead of "change the settings to the settings in this image")